# RxJava grouping elements of same type in a given timeframe while preserving order

Tags: rx-java

I have a hot observable that generates events of different types, and I would like to group together the events of the same type when they are emitted consecutively in a given timeframe, as follows:

**input**: "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "A4", "A5"

**output**: ("A1", "A2"), ("A3"), ("B1", "B2"), ("A4", "A5")

In the example above, the event "A3" arrives too late and is therefore not grouped with the events ("A1", "A2").

How can I do that with RxJava?

Comment: Perhaps `window(timespan, unit[, scheduler])` from http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html is what you need?

Comment: No it creates windows of elements that have been emitted in a specified timeframe, but does not group the elements by their type.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows

```
observable
  .scan(new ArrayList<T>(), groupingFunction)
  .lift(new DistinctUntilChanged<List<T>>())
```

where grouping function extends following class

```
public abstract class GroupingFunction<T> implements Func2<List<T>, T, List<T>> {

    @Override
    public List<T> call(List<T> group, T t) {
        if (group.isEmpty()) {
            group.add(t);
            return group;
        } 
        T first = group.get(0);
        if (isInSameGroup(first, t)) {
            group.add(t);
            return group;
        } else {
            List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
            result.add(t);
            return result;
        }
    }

    protected abstract boolean isInSameGroup(T left, T right);
}
```

here `isInSameGroup` defines grouping criteria and whether items are in same timeframe (it is also possible to merge source observable with `Observable.interval` to include time events, which can be then reacted to produce groups)

and `DistinctUntilChanged` is implemented as follows

```
public class DistinctUntilChanged<T> implements Operator<T, T> {

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> child) {
        return new Subscriber<T>(child) {
            T previousHolder = null;

            @Override
            public void onNext(T cur) {
                T prev = previousHolder;
                previousHolder = cur;

                if (prev != null) {
                    if (prev == cur) {
                        request(1);
                    } else {
                        child.onNext(prev);
                    }
                } else {
                    request(1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                child.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                if (previousHolder != null) child.onNext(previousHolder);
                child.onCompleted();
                previousHolder = null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

this implementation is similar to `rx.internal.operators.OperatorDistinctUntilChanged` but uses simple reference equality and emits last object that is not distinct, not the first one.

This should produce the grouping you require for consecutive items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for these answers.

I've spent some time on this problem, and finally found this solution:

```
            // buffer the events that occur in a given timeframe
            observable.buffer(timespan, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            // transform each buffer of events into a list of buffers of events of the same type, while preserving the order of the events
            .map(buffer ->
                buffer.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                this::getKey,
                                LinkedHashMap::new,
                                Collectors.toList())
                    ).values()
            )
            // flatten the list of buffers into buffers
            .flatMapIterable(bufferList -> bufferList)
            .subscribe(buffer -> LOGGER.info(buffer));
```

But this still looks a bit too complex to me. Is there any other solution?